# Linq to Lucene: "The predicate of a Lucene Term can not be the empty string."

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, lucene, lucene.net, linq-to-lucene

I am trying to implement Linq To Lucene in my project, but when trying to search for something, I am always getting a `Enumeration yielded no results` result and when I debug and try to open my `[IndexContext].[TableProperty]` in the `Watch` window, I am getting this message:

> The predicate of a Lucene Term can not
>   be the empty string.

I have tried searching in Google for this, but apparently it returned no results!

Has anyone ever encountered this message before?  And how can I fix it?  because currently it's not returning any data

**[Update]**

Apparently the problem is when I am using one of the Extension Methods (`Between`, `Match`, `Like` etc...) that are found in `Lucine.Linq.Extensions`.  Take the following example:

```
var db = new MusicRepo_DB_IndexContext(@"C:\MusicRepoDB_index",
                                       new MusicRepo_DBDataContext());
```

The following query returns a result: `db.Artists.Where(a => a.Name == "Camel");`

But this one doesn't: `db.Artists.Where(a => a.Search("Camel"));`

**[Update]**

Upon further testing, I realized that the `Match` extension method does actually return a result, wheres as the other ones (`Search`, `Like`) don't.  I'm still struggling with this issue

Answer (score 1):

I am using it in my project too and my belief is that this message shows up “The predicate of a Lucene Term can not be the empty string.”, because Lucene does not accept an empty term as a search criteria.

That's what happened to me:

(Northwind database)
When I tried to search

```
var mmCustomers = from c in dbi.Get<Customer>()
                      where c.ContactTitle == "Marketing Manager"                       
                      select c;
```

it works fine, but when I try:

```
var mmCustomers = from c in dbi.Get<Customer>()                       
                      select c;
```

it shows the “The predicate of a Lucene Term can not be the empty string.” error.

Hope it helps